# How to get the (.lnk) shortcut filepath in a program which started by the shortcut?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi

I have a c# program which open *.postfix file.

If a user runs a (.lnk)shortcut which points to my type of file, my program will open the target.

So, how could my program know it is started by a (.lnk)shortcut (and get it's file path)?

In some circumstances,i need to replace the .lnk file.

Thanks!

**Edited**
First, thanks to guys who answered my question.

By following @Anders answer, i find out my problem lays here.

I made some changes to windows registry, so browser knows to throw customized protocol string to certain program.

some thing like this..

[InternetShortcut]
URL=myProtocol://abcdefg.....

That's maybe why i lost lpTitle. :(

I'm going to try this way:
Whenever my program invoked, of course fed with %1, program checks current opened explorer(Window), and try to get it's current path with IWebBrowserApp. With that path and desktop of course, scan and analyze *.lnk to determine which one to replace.

I think this will probably work, but not be sure. I will try.
continued

Comment: I am not sure this possible. The .LNK file is *opened* by Explorer and that information is used to spawn the process (e.g. CreateProcess). I am not of if/how the information of *how* the process (or if a LNK file was involved) was started is made available...

Comment: Retagged this to winapi - in hopes that some guru on that end can provide a more thorough answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In native code you can call [GetStartupInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683230%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), if the `STARTF_TITLEISLINKNAME` bit is set in `STARTUPINFO.dwFlags` then the path to the .lnk is in `STARTUPINFO.lpTitle`. I don't know if there is a .NET way to get this info, you probably have to P/Invoke...

Comment: This brought me a little further. Until now, no .lnk filepath contained in my outputs. I should do more try, thanks anyway.

Comment: My shortcut content is [InternetShortcut]
URL=myProtocol://...... I think this causes the problem, lpTitle may have been consumed by explorer? Perhaps not. Still trying.. Thanks for ur google http://www.catch22.net/tuts/undoc01

Comment: .LNK's use the IShellLink interface, you are talking about IUniformResourceLocator and I'm not sure if the shell will pass you the path to it in the same way...

Answer (score 2):

You don't. There's no way to do it. End of story.

So this has been brought to my attention due to a recent downvote. There's an accepted answer showing an idea that gets the path to the launching shortcut most of the time. However my answer is to the whole. OP wants the link to the shortcut so he can change it. That is what can't be done most of the time.

Most likely case is the shortcut file exists in the start menu but is unwritable. However other cases involve the shortcut coming from another launching application that didn't even read it from a disk but from a database (I've seen a *lot* of corporate level restricted application launch tools). I also have a program that launches programs from shortcuts not via `IShellLink` but by parsing the `.lnk` file (because it must not start COM for reasons) and launching the program contained. It doesn't pass `STARTF_TITLEISLINKNAME` because it's passing an actual title.

Comment: Only if it's running before the user activates the shortcut, and be prepared for the answer to be somewhere other than a disk.

Comment: I got a service running on terminal already. I need to know how many ways to do that. Hook must be the last option, I don't familiar with hook (especially doing this). Any one can leave a link here or a proper search key word? THK.

Comment: @Joshua Why would you answer with "There's no way to do it. End of story."? How can you be so sure? Have you done any research at all? The second I saw the question title I knew the answer so I assume some google searching would also find the answer...

Comment: Users do not expect programs to modify their shortcuts. If I create a shortcut to Z with option X, then I expect it to remain a shortcut to Z with option X and not get secretly changed to something else behind my back.

Comment: @Anders: Your solution doesn't work in all cases. Hidden assumption: the launching program is explorer or used ShellExec to open the .lnk file. Corollary: The .lnk is on a disk. Raymond blogged about it being possible to store the link contents in a database awhile back but my google-fu is not currently strong enough to find it.

Comment: Further hidden assumption: the .lnk file is not on the shared desktop or other not-guaranteed-writable location.

Comment: @Joshua: ShellExecute/IContextMenu is probably the only way to launch a shortcut so I don't know how big of an assumption this is. I know you can serialize it, but it is on disk when STARTF_TITLEISLINKNAME is set (And it probably has to be on disk to execute it in the first place). Whether it is writable is irrelevant when it comes to figuring out if you were started from a .lnk or not. (Any file on a system can be open with non-shared write access etc)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Visual Studio Setup Project to build an installer and do the file type association, you should follow these instructions http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/58005-file-associations-in-visual-studio/

1. Open up your solution in Visual studio.
2. Add a Setup Project to your solution by file , add project,New project, Setup & Deployment projects,Setup project
3. Right-click on your setup project in the "Solution Explorer" window,Select view,then select file types.

   you'll see the "file types" window displayed in Visual studio.At the top of the window will be "File types on target machine"
4. Right-click on "File types on target machine".the menu will pop up with Add "file type" Click on this.

   you'll see "New document Type#1" added,and "&open"underneath it.
5. The "new document type#1" can be anything you want - change it to something descriptive.although the user never sees this,never use something common- be as unique as possible,Because you can overlay current file associations without even realizing it.For example,you might think"pngfile" might be a useful name- but using that will now send all"*.png" files to your application,instead of to an image viewer.A good practice maybe "YourCompantName.Filetype",where your company name is your name of your company's name, and "Filetype" is a descriptive text of your file.
6. In the "properties" window for your new type,you will need to change a few properties.:

   Command:Change to the application that you want to run.If you click on the "..." and you will proberly want to locate and use the "primary Output..." File
   Description: This is the description of the file type(if it doesn't describe it's self"
   Extensions:This your list of extensions for you chosen Program.Separate each one with a ","
   Icon:This will associate the icon with your file type,This shows up in the window explorer.
7. Now we move to that "&open ".This is an action that is available if your right-click on the file.The default action("&Open" is currently set as the default) is what happens when you double click on the file.Right click on your "New document type#1" to add actions,but for the moment,lets define our "&open" action

   Click on "&Open".You will see in the properties window "Name","Arguments","Verbs". Verb is hidden from the user,but is the key that is stored in the registry.Leave it same as the name,But without the "&".The default for"Arguments" is "%1",Which means to pass the full path and filename to your application.You can add other stuff here as well,if you need to pass flags to your application to do special stuff.All this infomaton is getting passed to your application on the command line,so you'll need to be familiar with the "Environment.CommandLine" object.
   If you need to set a different action as your default,just right click on the action and "set as default"

Basically, you'll pass the file path as an argument to your program. Then if it's a console application or Windows Forms , you should check the arguments in Program.Main

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  //if file association done with Arguments %1 as per forum post above  
  //you file path should be in args[0]
  string filePath = null;
  if(args != null && args.Length > 0)
     filePath = args[0];
}
```

For a WPF application you'll need to handle that in the StartUp event for your Application

```
 void App_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
 {
    string filePath = null;
    if ((e.Args != null) && (e.Args.Length > 0))
    {
       filePath = e.Args[0];
    }
 }
```

Comment: Emmanuel, this is a very helpful and well-written post, but is unfortunately not at all what the original poster was looking for. They want to know if I create a new shortcut to the program and then I click on that shortcut, what is the name of the .lnk file that contains the shortcut.